# Load testing of Infinispan v5.1 cache

Tags: caching, wildfly-8, infinispan

In our project, WildFly v8.1 application server is used and Infinispan v5.1 is used as a cache. Currently, we are facing delay in query results from infinispan while running load.

Earlier it was used with JBoss v5.1 and Infinispan v5.1 there were no performance issues.

Could anyone tell us how infinispan performance can be tested? Which tool can we use for measuring the performance of cache?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

There are at least two things that bother me in your question.

The first one is that you shouldn't use Infinispan modules from Wildfly directly. This version is used internally for Wildfly clustering. What I encourage you to do is to use the latest [Infinispan Wildfly Modules](http://downloads.jboss.org/infinispan/8.2.2.Final/infinispan-as-embedded-modules-8.2.2.Final.zip). All you need to do is to unpack them into the Wildfly modules directory and use proper slot in your code (`MANIFEST.MF` or `jboss-deployment-structure.xml`).

Secondly, measuring performance is a very tricky business. You need to consider proper JGroups configuration, adjust GC settings, use proper cluster size and much more. I would recommend measuring performance of your application **together with Infinispan** (this way you will give you more meaningful results for your team). There are many tools which can help you with that including [JMH](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jmh/) or [Caliper](https://github.com/google/caliper). If you are interested in measuring only Infinispan performance - you might consider using [RadarGun](https://github.com/radargun/radargun).